# F3 robot communications protocol?

Tags: robotic-arm

I am considering writing a program to communicate with a Thermo Scientific F3 robot arm in order to eliminate their obsolete C500C controller.  Does anyone know the communications protocol to/from the F3?  All I know is that it is RS485.

Thanks

Comment: You should look at the drive amplifiers and their documentation. Those are very likely not developed by Thermo Scientific and with a bit of look you will find the specification of their communication protocol.